# Ionic Diretiva para mascara numérica não é acessada de outras páginas

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

Criei um projeto com Ionic com duas páginas: Login e registro.

A estrutura é esta

[image: Estrutura]

Em ambas tentei adicionar uma diretiva que cria uma máscara para CNPJ.
Segue código da diretiva

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[mask]',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: MaskDirective,
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class MaskDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

    onTouched: any;
    onChange: any;

    @Input('mask') mask: string;

    writeValue(value: any): void {
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
    onKeyup($event: any) {
        var valor = $event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        var pad = this.mask.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/9/g, '_');
        var valorMask = valor + pad.substring(0, pad.length - valor.length);

        // retorna caso pressionado backspace
        if ($event.keyCode === 8) {

            if (this.onChange != undefined) {
                this.onChange(valor);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (valor.length <= pad.length && this.onChange != undefined) {
            this.onChange(valor);
        }

        var valorMaskPos = 0;
        valor = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < this.mask.length; i++) {
            if (isNaN(parseInt(this.mask.charAt(i)))) {
                valor += this.mask.charAt(i);
            } else {
                valor += valorMask[valorMaskPos++];
            }
        }

        if (valor.indexOf('_') > -1) {
            valor = valor.substr(0, valor.indexOf('_'));
        }

        $event.target.value = valor;
    }

    @HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
    onBlur($event: any) {
        if ($event.target.value.length === this.mask.length) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.onChange != undefined) {
            this.onChange('');
        }
        $event.target.value = '';
    }
}
```

Para utilizar seria só adicionar no login.html

```
 <ion-input type="tel" maxlength="18" name="cnpj" mask="99.999.999/9999-99" [(ngModel)]="registerCredentials.cnpj" required></ion-input>
```

e no registro

```
<ion-input type="tel" maxlength="18" name="cnpj" mask="99.999.999/9999-99" required></ion-input>`
```

Login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ServiceProvider } from '../../providers/service/service';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  registerCredentials: any = { cnpj: '', senha: '' };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private serviceProvider: ServiceProvider) {
  }

  public criarConta() {
    this.navCtrl.push('RegistroPage');
  }

  public login() {

    this.serviceProvider.post('autenticacao/autenticarEmpresa', { id: 1 }).subscribe(dados => {
      debugger
    });
  }

}
```

Meu app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { ServiceProvider } from '../providers/service/service';
import { MaskDirective } from '../directives/MaskDirective ';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    MaskDirective,
    LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    ServiceProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Quando executo o código na pagina de login o texto é formatado, porem quando vou para a página de cadastro não é executada a diretiva.
Acredito que seja alguma coisa com a modularização, como exportar esta diretiva para o módulo das páginas.

No login.module.ts e registro.module.ts não foi alterado nada

Como Posso fazer para tornar esta diretiva visivel nos dois módulos?

Tambem dei uma pesquisada no google e vi alguma coisa de tornar esta diretiva um módulo.

Se a solução for adicionar em um módulo. como faço isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso o [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) nos meus projetos, é bem fácil de usá-lo.

1- Configura ele no app.module e depois no componente que vai usá-lo.
2- No `input`, digite `mask='(00)00000-0000'`

E tá pronto!
Qualquer dúvida, só me avisa que insiro um exemplo de código.